# Mobile version dosn't end with content- "margin" on the right

Tags: css, mobile, responsive, responsiveness

I'm working on the mobile version of my wesite and for some reason I got a right margin next to my content header etc (take a look at the screenshot). 
[Screenshot responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3gRc.jpg)
In chrome developer tools I checked why the background is visible on the right side and I can see that the right "margin" is inside my  #wrapper. How can I fix this? Already tried to change the width of the wrapper but nothing has helped. 
Thank you!

This is my HTML

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media Management</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper" class="hidden-mobile">
    <nav class="hidden-mobile" id="menue">
      <div class="navItem">
      <img src="./img/home_website.png" class="icon"  id="homeicon"><br>
      <a class="icontitle" id="current" href="./index.html">HOME</a>
      <div class="after"></div>
    </div>
      <div class="navItem">
      <img src="./img/studieninteressierte.png"class="icon"><br>
       <a class="icontitle" href="./fotowand.html">STUDIEN-<br>INTERESSIERTE</a>
       <div class="after"></div>
     </div>
      <div class="navItem">
       <img src="./img/studierende.png" class="icon" id="studierendeicon"><br>
       <a class="icontitle" href="">STUDIERENDE</a>
       <div class="after"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="navItem">
      <img src="./img/unternehmen.png" class="icon" id="unternehmenicon"><br>
       <a class="icontitle" href="">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
       <div class="after"></div>
     </div>
       <div class="navItem">
       <img src="./img/kontakt.png" class="icon"><br>
       <a class="icontitle" href="">KONTAKT</a>
       <div class="after"></div>
     </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
      <header>
        <img src="./img/Burgermenü.png" class="only-mobile" id="burgermenue">
       <a href="http://www.hs-rm.de/de/"> <img src="./img/hsrm_logo.png"  id="hsrmlogo">
       </a>
       <div id="headertitel">
       <h1>Media Management</h1>
         <h2>Bachelor of Science</h2>
       </div>
     </header>
      <main>
        <div class="content">
        <h1>Aktuelles</h1>
          <h2>6. Karriere Forum Media Management</h2>
          <p>
            Am 17. Mai fand das sechste Karriere Forum Media Management statt - eine Veranstaltung des Studiengangs Media Management in Zusammenarbeit mit dem Competence & Career Center der Hochschule RheinMain. Den interessierten Studierenden bot sich ein vielfältiger Eindruck vom Einstieg in das Berufsleben und der täglichen -praxis.

      Das Karriere Forum, moderiert von Prof. Dr. Christoph Kochhan, startete mit einem Vortrag von Hans Reitz (Geschäftsführer, circ GmbH & co. kg),  der im Rahmen seiner spannenden Präsentation zum Thema Live Communication auch auf die Bedeutung der eigenen Persönlichkeitsentwicklung im Rahmen der Beruftätigkeit hinwies. Paul Herwarth von Bittenfeld (Product Owner, Seibert Media) stellte mit dem Kollegen Lukas Pfeifer (Consultant und Projektmanager) sowie der Kollegin Alisa Tietz (Product Marketing Managerin) die Arbeit in einer Media-Agentur mit ihren unterschiedlichen Aufgabenbereichen dar. Carla-Maria Balster, ehemalige Absolventin des Studiengangs Media Management, berichtete kurzweilig von ihrem Weg vom Studium an der Hochschule RheinMain zu ihrem jetzigen Job als Key Account Managerin bei Unitymedia.

      Flankiert wurden die interessanten Vorträge von einer Vielzahl an Fragen der Studierenden. Die angehenden Media Managerinnen und Manager nutzten die Chance, im Rahmen der Veranstaltung wertvolle Impulse aus den Diskussionen mit den Referentinnen und Referenten mitzunehmen.

      Für die siebte Auflage des Karriere Forums Media Management stehen erneut hochkarätige Experten zur Verfügung, um den Studierenden wichtige Einblicke in das spätere Berufsleben zu geben.
      Am 17. Mai fand das sechste Karriere Forum Media Management statt - eine Veranstaltung des Studiengangs Media Management in Zusammenarbeit mit dem Competence & Career Center der Hochschule RheinMain. Den interessierten Studierenden bot sich ein vielfältiger Eindruck vom Einstieg in das Berufsleben und der täglichen -praxis.

Das Karriere Forum, moderiert von Prof. Dr. Christoph Kochhan, startete mit einem Vortrag von Hans Reitz (Geschäftsführer, circ GmbH & co. kg),  der im Rahmen seiner spannenden Präsentation zum Thema Live Communication auch auf die Bedeutung der eigenen Persönlichkeitsentwicklung im Rahmen der Beruftätigkeit hinwies. Paul Herwarth von Bittenfeld (Product Owner, Seibert Media) stellte mit dem Kollegen Lukas Pfeifer (Consultant und Projektmanager) sowie der Kollegin Alisa Tietz (Product Marketing Managerin) die Arbeit in einer Media-Agentur mit ihren unterschiedlichen Aufgabenbereichen dar. Carla-Maria Balster, ehemalige Absolventin des Studiengangs Media Management, berichtete kurzweilig von ihrem Weg vom Studium an der Hochschule RheinMain zu ihrem jetzigen Job als Key Account Managerin bei Unitymedia.

Flankiert wurden die interessanten Vorträge von einer Vielzahl an Fragen der Studierenden. Die angehenden Media Managerinnen und Manager nutzten die Chance, im Rahmen der Veranstaltung wertvolle Impulse aus den Diskussionen mit den Referentinnen und Referenten mitzunehmen.

Für die siebte Auflage des Karriere Forums Media Management stehen erneut hochkarätige Experten zur Verfügung, um den Studierenden wichtige Einblicke in das spätere Berufsleben zu geben.

      Prof. Dr. Christoph Kochhan, 18.05.2017
          </p>
      </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
html, body {
  background-image: url("../img/steinwand2.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
/*Flexbox*/
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;


}

#menue {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;


}

#content {
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  flex-flow: column;

}

header{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 435px;
  background-image: url("../img/baum.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 70% 70%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;

}

main {
  height:100%

}

/*Flexbox*/

/*Navigation*/
#burgermenue{
  width:80px;
}

.icontitle{
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#current{
  font-weight: bold;
}
#studierendeicon{
  width:130px;
background-image: url('./img/studierende.png')
background-position: center center;
}

#unternehmenicon{
  width:60px;
}

#homeicon{
  width:70px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.navItem {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width:130px;
  height: 140px;
}

.icon {
  width:80px;
}

.after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}

.navItem:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
 transform: scale(1.2);

}


/*Navigation Ende*/

.content{
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);

}

#hsrmlogo{
  width: 250px;
 position: relative;
 left: 80%;
}

#headertitel{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top:50%;
  right:3%;
}


/*Media Queries*/
.only-mobile, .only-tablet, .only-tablet {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width:768px)  { /*Smartphone*/
  .hidden-mobile {
  display: none;
  }

  .only-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
#burgermenue{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:100px;
  z-index: 51;
}
 #menue{
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   height:300px;
   background-color: grey;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-around;
   z-index: 50;
 }

.navItem{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;


}
.icon{
  display: none;
}
header{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
  background-image: url("../img/baum.jpg");
}

#headertitel{
  position: absolute;
  right:50%;
  top:15%;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.content{
  margin: 5px;
}

#hsrmlogo{
  position: absolute;
  top:1px;
  left:250px;
  width:200px;
}


  @media (max-width:991px) and (min-width:769px){ /*Tablet*/


  @media (min-width:992px) { /*Desktop*/

  }
  /*Media Queries Ende*/
```

Comment: Can you prune the example code down to the absolute minimum required to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Sure I could but the problem is I cant really understand where the problem is

Comment: It's hard to say with the code you've posted, but `.navItem:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}` might be a problem, `#hsrmlogo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 200px;
}` might be another one

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following rule:

```
#content {
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

It is making `#content` 90% the width of its container. The gap you see is the remaining 10%.

I imagine that you only want that rule to kick in at desktop widths, so one way of fixing the problem is to wrap it in a media query:

```
@media (min-width:769px)  {
    #content {
      flex: 0 0 90%;
      flex-flow: column;
    }
}
```